# web service .asmx not compiling correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx

I am trying to create a webservice in c# that can be called from jquery.

I have created the webservice in visual studio and it works when I press F5, but when I try to upload it I get different results. I'm even publishing though VS straight to FTP yet when viewing the page I get this

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="Service1.asmx.cs" Class="WebService1.Service1" %>
```

This is the same message I am getting returned to my jquery when requesting a get. Any ideas why it isn't working?

Comment: Sounds like an IIS issue. What version of IIS are you using on your server? Also, do .aspx pages render properly?

Comment: If the webserver responds with the source of your *Service1.asmx* file content the problem is very likely that the server doesn't know how to process it.

Comment: If you get the content of the asmx file, you probably don't have asp.net installed properly. What kind of server is it ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the virtual path in IIS is defined as an Application.  Look here for more info:

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772042(WS.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772042%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error (after what I think was due to rebinding - through Add Service Reference - to a web service in a new version of Visual Studio). I noticed I had ended up with duplicate .asmx files. Try deleting the .asmx files and rebind to the web service from scratch through Add Service Reference in Visual Studio Solution Explorer